# Can't seem to pass a variable to my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for a comment. Comments belongs_to Issue. I have a comments form on my issue#show view, which is where my form_for is. I create the comment object @comment in my issue#show controller action. When i submit the form, it calls the comment#create controller action. However, I need a variable called :issue_id. I have issue_id in the issue#show view, and I can even set the @comment object to have issue_id. However, when it gets passed to the comments#create controller, the issue_id isn't being passed in the params[:comment] so when the comment gets created and saved, it's not there. Here are my files:

issue#show view:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
    <%= render 'comment_fields', :f => f %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

issue#show controller:

```
  def show
    @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
    @votes = Votership.where(:issue_id => @issue.id)
    @current_user_vote = @votes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
    @comment = Comment.new(:issue_id => @issue.id)
  end
```

and the comments#create controller where the comment gets created:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

I tried adding a hidden field in the form, but it kept creating a hash of values and the key would be the issue_id but I couldn't figure out how to set the value of the hidden field, which is weird. How do I do this correctly?

PS comments belong_to issues. issues has many comments. issues belongs_to apps. apps has many issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not actually understand your complain but from what i understand you are trying to get the issue id to be saved with the comment. you should have a hidden field in your form like

```
<%= f.hidden_field :issue_id %>
```

if this is not the solution you need pls let me know so i can help again.

Comment: oh my !!! I have been trying to get this to work for so long...this worked!  thank you. now...is this the best way to do it? when i prepare the object for the form, it contains issue_id, is there a better way to pass that info to the comments#create controller actioN?